# Changing the format of a weird data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a csv file that contains a really weird table that I want to format in a proper way.

The Background:
Students are able to answer questions on an online platform. The questions are labeled Test1, Test2, Test3. The three questions are presented as packs, but the order of questions is randomized. It can be Test1, Test2, Test3 or Test2, Test3, Test1 etc.

I can download the results in a csv file. If I put the results to a dataframe, it looks like this.

[image: Original Format]

What I need for an analysis of the results is the following format:

[image: Desired Format]

I was thinking about localising each occurrence of "Name" in the first column to cut the dataframe into single data frames, where each dataframe represents one student, like this:

[image: StudentA]

[image: StudentB]

For StudentB, I could just rearrange the columns, so it looks like

[image]

I could then remove the column descriptions of every student that is ordered as StudentB and put them back together, giving me

[image]

Although I am a R Beginner, im pretty confident I could find a way to do that, BUT how can I reorder StudentA?

So my first question: Which is a better way to do this?
Second question: What about students that answered multiple tests?

Best regards!

Comment: Can you include a runnable example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will do what you want:

(EDIT: Updated to reflect the change to the problem according to the comment from OP)

```r
library(tidyr)

# Read in the test data
dat <- read.csv("data_v2.csv", header=F, colClasses="character")
dat

reformat.student.data <- function(dat) {
    # To group together the rows belonging to each student
    grouprows <- cumsum(dat[,1] == "Name")

    # Function to rearrange the data for a single student
    f <- function(x) {
        Name <- x[2, 1]
        y <- unlist(x[, -1])
        n <- length(y)
        w <- y[seq(1, n-1, 2)]
        w <- paste0(1:(nrow(x)/2), "_", w)
        v <- y[seq(2, n, 2)]
        data.frame(Name, w, v, stringsAsFactors=F)[order(w),]
    }

    # Use `by` to apply the function to each student
    dat2 <- do.call(rbind, by(dat, grouprows, f))

    # Use `spread` to reshape the data
    dat3 <- tidyr::spread(dat2, w, v)

    dat3 # The desired results
}
reformat.student.data(dat)
```

This is the test data:

```r
> dat
##     V1    V2    V3    V4
## 1 Name Test1 Test2 Test3
## 2    A     1     2     1
## 3      Test1 Test2 Test3
## 4          1     1     2
## 5      Test2 Test3 Test1
## 6          1     2     1
## 7 Name Test2 Test1 Test3
## 8    B     1     2     1
```

And this is the result:

```r
> reformat.student.data(dat)
##   Name 1_Test1 1_Test2 1_Test3 2_Test1 2_Test2 2_Test3 3_Test1 3_Test2
## 1    A       1       2       1       1       1       2       1       1
## 2    B       2       1       1    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
##   3_Test3
## 1       2
## 2    <NA>
```

Edit: improved code slightly.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I could reproduce what you did with the dataset you provided. Sadly I noticed that my dataset doesn't look like the way I thought it would. The tests aren't numbered in the correct way.

Instead of 1_Test1 or 2_Test1 both are labeled as Test1.

Is it possible to add a leading number in the function f?

Comment: Again, thank you very much! I had to change some variables, but now everything is working as intended. I will probably spend the rest of the day figuring out what each line of you code does!